# Same thermistor model (103) with varying response

Tags: adc, thermistor

I was using thermistor model 103 to measure temperature of surroundings. To my surprise, when I checked different thermistors of the same model (103) bought from the same shop by changing them in the circuit, each had their own resistive response to the surrounding temperature. Like the first thermistor gave an error of 1.5 degrees celcius and other 2.5, due to varied resistive response.

My question is:

How can these thermistors of same model differ in the way they measure temperature and what can be a universal solution to all thermistors of this model to be accurate?

Comment: Maybe this is due to "high" tolerance on this model (103) ? you can buy 1% tolerance device to 10% tolerance (between announced value & real one)  device & maybe more.

Comment: what is the exact thermistor being used?  Datasheet? Circuit being used to measure it?

Comment: I did not get any attached datasheet along with it. They also did not specify anything

Comment: No data sheet?  Then you're just going at this blind.  Go out and get a part that has some documentation with it.

Comment: How are you calculating temperature from the resistance?

Comment: Sundar - If you really want us to help you need to give us some more information.  We need to know 1) what is your accuracy requirement; 2) what temperature resolution do you need; 3) over what temperature range do you need to meet these requirements; 4) Do you care more about absolute accuracy, repeatability, or something else???

Comment: Sorry for the late reply , apologize and appreciate people’s helping tendency. 1) accuracy requirement : atleast 1 degree celcius , 2) temperature resolution you mean adc resolution ? Then it is 10bit resolution.3) temperature range 25 to 45 degree celcius 4) Absolute accuracy and non variation of values to a particular extent.

Answer (score 1):

The allowable variation in the thermistor characteristics should be defined in the component datasheet. If the parts you purchased are not meeting the datasheet limits then you should return them to the supplier.

There is no solution that will make all thermistors of a given type "accurate", because there will always be variation in the components. If you want to limit the variability then you must make this part of your purchasing agreement. The other solution is to perform a final calibration procedure to determine the unique correction needed for each unit, and store the correction parameters in some kind of non-volatile memory.

Comment: Or a trimpot...

Comment: A trimpot would allow you to correct the thermistor at just **one** temperature.

Comment: Trimpot ? Can you pls share me how to implement it? Like circuit or any software examples you have?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two parameters when you specify a thermistor. Resistance at a reference temperature (in your case 10K at 25°C, most likely) and \$\beta\$. The latter gives you the nominal resistance change between two specified temperatures. Both of those parameters have an associated tolerance.

For example, a TDK B57863S0103F040 thermistor is 10K nominal  at 25°C and has a nominal \$\beta\$ of 3988K between 25 and 100°C.

This particular part is specified to have a total tolerance including beta and nominal value of +/-0.2 kelvin.

If you stick a part with a beta of 3988K into a circuit designed for a different beta, it will read correctly (within tolerance) at 25°C but will deviate from the ideal reading further the further you get from the reference 25°C temperature. If you trim the error out at one temperature it will be inaccurate at other temperatures.

So to substitute a part and have it perform accurately you must know at least those two parameters, and the desired tolerances. Typically a 1% tolerance represents a couple tenths of a kelvin.

If you want a "universal" solution you can measure the resistance and implement the nonlinear equation for the temperature as a function of resistance. Popular equations include the simplified equation with \$\beta\$ and the Steinhart-Hart equation which requires more parameters. Since thermistors are extremely nonlinear you need to have a wide dynamic range in the resistance measurement to get good resolution and accuracy over a wide temperature range. It's a lot easier if you're just measuring near some fixed temperature such as human body temperature.

Comment: Yes im going to measure the temperature of a dog ! Now im testing the thermistor with the  temperature values of my surrounding (air conditioned room) and comparing it with an accurate temperature measuring instrument! Is my way correct? I use steinhart equation to arrive at my temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet if you do a sensitivity analysis of your temperature measuring circuit, and given the initial tolerance and resistance vs temperature characteristic variability of the part you're using, you find that those temperature differences are within expected bounds.

By sensitivity analysis, I mean you have know how much the resistance of the thermistor varies with temperature.  Then you basically take the derivative of that function (curve) to come up the sensitivity of the circuit, in ohms/deg C.  This will probably not be constant, and could vary quite a bit across your temperature range.

From that sensitivity, and using the data sheet tolerance and other information, you can estimate what kind temperature error is consistent with your part and circuit.

Edit 1: Answer OP's question

"Universal solution" - depends on what your measurement accuracy requirements are, which I don't think you've told us.  Also, it makes a difference whether you're concerned about absolute accuracy or just repeatability.

You can improve the initial uncertainty, at least at 25C, by procuring 1% (or better) tolerance parts.  You could do a calibration of your monitoring circuit (excitation method, amplifier chain [if any], ADC error) to help ameliorate those errors.

Comment: Do I have any universal solution? Like in the software side? Becoz if Im going to release it as a product , do I have to manually estimate the sensitivity and then do the corrections for each thermistor individually?

Comment: My sensitivity variation is approximately 7degree celcius ! Like I added 7 degrees to the returning temperature value to arrive at the desired temperature value, but still its like varying to a considerble extent , if I keep testing with many thermistors.